# Jquery to get the data of a row with the row id

Tags: jquery, popup

I have the row id available of a table, then how is it to get the contents of the row having three columns into my JS variables. Iam trying to bring the contents of a row into my popup, so i put a check box and when it is checked i can get the row id. The next step was to populate the data into my popup. I thought of calling an Ajax request , but there should be a JQuery way to get the data?

EDIT :

This is how i get the row number from the check box

```
if ($('.cbox1:checked').length) {
        var id = '';
        $('.cbox1:checked').each(function () {
        id = $(this).val();
});
```

The HTML of the row where i populate from Table is :

```
<tr contenteditable="false" class="content<?php echo $record->ID;?>" id="<?php echo $record->ID;?>">
```

Comment: What kind of table are we talking about? An html table or a database table on some server?

Comment: its a html table populated with the contents from a database using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's truly an ID, then it should be unique to the entire DOM. So, you can just query it.

```
var columns = [];
$('#yourRowId').find('td').each(function(){
    columns.push($(this).text());
});


console.log(columns);
```

I'm not sure what kind of popup you are talking about. If it is an entirely separate page opening in a new window, you will not be able to access the DOM of the original page. So, an alternative would be when they perform the action to cause the popup to show, tack on the data as query parameters and then read the parameters off the url in the popup. Otherwise, you might need to incorporate some backend logic into things.

Comment: the id of the row i am getting is via a checkbox selection. so its a unique number of the row

Comment: Is it an HTML ID, or is it an INDEX of a row?

Comment: Great, then the above should work okay for you (if the popup is not a separate window). If it is, you'll have to read the data and set the columns as query parameters on the url that you open for the popup. Then you can read them in the popup off the current url.

Comment: a small doubt ...with id as the JS variable . is it like this **$('.content+id')**

Comment: but iam getting empty array in console

Comment: nope, it's an ID as populated here: `id="<?php echo $record->ID;?>"`. Don't forget the `#` at the beginning (even though it's not in your actual ID attribute, that's standard CSS selector notation).

Comment: so, using your id variable: `$('#' + id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68596/discussion-between-master-mind-and-paul-r).

Comment: again a small problem -can u help how to do the reverse. That is loading the contents of table with the jQuery